# How to see when a point in time has passed in Python

Tags: python, time

I'm using the following code in a calendar to tell me how long I have until I need to be up for an event. There's 2 portions, one that displays the time until work starts, and another that displays how long before I need to wake up for work.

```
work_alarm = timedelta(hours=2, minutes=30)
a_n = int((we_dt - tct).total_seconds() / 60) # to get minutes remaining from the current time to when work starts
alarm_time = we_dt - work_alarm
up_time = int((alarm_time - tct).total_seconds() / 60) # total minutes until I need to be up
print "Scheduled Work Time: " + str(we_dt.strftime('%H:%M'))
print "You have " + str(we[1]) + " in " + str(int((((we_dt - tct).total_seconds() / 60) / 60))) + " hours and " + str(divmod(a_n, 60)[1]) + " minutes."
print "You need to be up in " + str(int((((alarm_time - tct).total_seconds() / 60) / 60))) + " hours and " + str(divmod(up_time, 60)[1]) + " minutes."
```

That all works just fine, until the "You need to be up" time passes.  After the event time passes, it stops reporting it, so that's not really a concern, but I would like to set up an if statement of sorts that can check or tell if the you need to be up time has passed and stop displaying it.  Because as it stands right now, after that time has passed, it just starts going up in numbers the opposite direction.  For example:  If there is 1 minute left until I need to be up, after it hits zero, it just starts going up: 1, 2, 3 minutes etc. afterwards.  The number doesn't display as a negative integer, so I'm not sure how to run a comparison on this so I can stop it from displaying once the time has passed. As a note in case it matters, this script is run every minute using an apscheduler module.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: You might want to get rid of those excessively long lines and make your code a bit more readable.

Comment: As an aside, your code would be more readable if you used string formatting, as in: `"You need to be up in {hrs:d} hours and {min:d} minutes".format(hrs=up_time/60, min=up_time%60)`

Comment: I agree. You should separate the formatting and priming-of-data from the calculation, in order to help yourself and others understand your code better.

Comment: If your `up_time` variable decreases towards a value of 0 as it nears the time to wake up, and then starts increasing after it reaches it, you have a bug in your code, or at least a logical error. It's hard to tell you where this problem could be coming from since important variables like `tct` and `we_dt` aren't defined in the code provided, nor do they have easily guessable content from their names. Need more information.

Comment: As there are several functions that result to this point in the code it would have been difficult to show you the areas where each variable used is initially defined. The part that generates the tct variable is about 20 lines in where as this particular section is about 80 or so lines in. The we_dt variable is created off other variables that are defined over 100 lines down.  The first person answering understood my goal and fixed it just as I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a function to return the hours, minutes (and seconds) between two datetimes:

```
def time_between(a, b):
    minutes, seconds = divmod((b-a).total_seconds(), 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    return hours, minutes, seconds
```

Using this function, most of your calculations can be separated from the code that prints. That, along with using more descriptive variable names will make your code easier to understand:

```
import datetime as DT

def time_between(a, b):
    minutes, seconds = divmod((b-a).total_seconds(), 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    return hours, minutes, seconds

# current time
tct = DT.datetime.now()
# job datetime (just for example)
we_dt = tct + DT.timedelta(hours=3, minutes=30)

work_alarm = DT.timedelta(hours=2, minutes=30)

# time till work
work_hours, work_minutes, work_seconds = time_between(tct, we_dt)

# time till get up
up_time = we_dt - work_alarm
up_hours, up_minutes, up_seconds = time_between(tct, up_time)
print("""\
Scheduled Work Time: {wt}
You have {we} in {h} + hours and {m} minutes.""".format(
          wt=we_dt.strftime('%H:%M'),
          we='something to do',
          h=work_hours,
          m=work_minutes))

if up_time > tct:
    print('You need to be up in {uh}  hours and {um} minutes.'.format(
        uh=up_hours,
        um=up_minutes))
```

Comment: Your answer was very clear and an interesting concept. This should make it significantly easier.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You just need an `if` statement here that doesn't display anything if the value is negative.

You say "The number doesn't display as a negative integer", but you're not displaying the number. You're displaying `str(divmod(up_time, 60))[1]`. So, if `up_time` is -3, it displays at `57`… but `up_time` itself is still a negative number.

```
work_alarm = timedelta(hours=2, minutes=30)
a_n = int((we_dt - tct).total_seconds() / 60) # to get minutes remaining from the current time to when work starts
alarm_time = we_dt - work_alarm
up_time = int((alarm_time - tct).total_seconds() / 60) # total minutes until I need to be up
if up_time >= 0:
    print "Scheduled Work Time: " + str(we_dt.strftime('%H:%M'))
    print "You have " + str(we[1]) + " in " + str(int((((we_dt - tct).total_seconds() / 60) / 60))) + " hours and " + str(divmod(a_n, 60)[1]) + " minutes."
    print "You need to be up in " + str(int((((alarm_time - tct).total_seconds() / 60) / 60))) + " hours and " + str(divmod(up_time, 60)[1]) + " minutes."
```

Or, even better, tell the scheduler to not call your code when the work time is in the past. Without seeing your scheduler code, it's hard to say how to do that—maybe adjust the schedule until tomorrow morning in an `else` here, or maybe build a more complicated schedule in the first place, or …